# Restricting access to a web directory using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security

I want to restrict access to certain web directories in my website using .htaccess file. I know one way using 
 
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 
But it restricts only the first directory. It doesn't work for the remaining ones. Please help

Comment: @jimy, What will giving permisison of `755` do in OP's case

Comment: @jimy: Thanks jimy. It works. You should have posted this as an answer. I would have closed it

Comment: What i can't figure out is, Why would this question belong on `serverfault.com`? It is not that off topic.

Comment: @sanks dont try that one it will also not give access while page rendering try out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Options -Indexes` add this line at the top  of the .htaccess file

Comment: What's that? I didn't understand. How can this help?

Comment: this will not give access to any other file rather than index.php, home.php etc

Comment: Can you explain in short about this? Please

Answer (score 5):

You are wrong, using `deny from all` also applies to subdirectories.

<sub>i.e. unless there is another `.htaccess` inside the other sub directories that allows the access</sub>

Comment: I didn't understand. can you elaborate

Comment: If you allow access to a sub directory by placing another `.htaccess` file inside it, on that case only the `deny from all` placed at the parent directory does not work. Or else it will restrict access to every directory found.